# Do I add my level of Dragon Disciple to my caster level to determine the duration of my Shield spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, duration

I'm creating a Fighter/Sorcerer Dragon Disciple. My intention is to only get 1 level of Sorcerer for the Shield spell. Do I add my level of Dragon Disciple to my caster level for my Shield spell duration, or will it only be 1 min/level until I level up Sorcerer? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site AdamZ! This sounds like a Pathfinder 1st Edition question, rather than a Pathfinder 2nd Edition one. Is that right? If so, you should update the tag on this question.

Comment: @NautArch Spell durations don't increase with caster level in Pathfinder 2E. The comment around taking 1 level of Sorcerer also matches PF1E rather than PF2E.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming from context that this is a Pathfinder 1st Edition question:*

### Levels of Dragon Disciple generally increase your caster level for sorcerer spells, but not every Dragon Disciple level... see below

[Dragon Disciples](https://aonprd.com/PrestigeClassesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dragon%20Disciple) have the following class feature at all levels except 1st, 5th and 9th:

> **Spells per Day:** At the indicated levels, a dragon disciple gains new spells per day as if he had also gained a level in an arcane spellcasting class he belonged to before adding the prestige class. He does not, however, gain other benefits a character of that class would have gained, except for additional spells per day, spells known (if he is a spontaneous spellcaster), *and an increased effective level of spellcasting*. If a character had more than one arcane spellcasting class before becoming a dragon disciple, he must decide to which class he adds the new level for purposes of determining spells per day.

The text I've italicized above tells you that at each level other than 1st, 5th and 9th, your caster level for your sorcerer spells increases by 1. So while your dragon disciple level doesn't fully stack with your sorcerer level to determine spell durations, it does partially stack.

Comment: I don't think we should technically be answer this until the OP clarifies that you're correct about the edition... but this *is* the only situation in which it makes sense and this *is* accurate so I'm not sure

Comment: @Ifusaso - per the top answer on [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11723/64464), it's fine, albeit at the answerer's own risk. (Admittedly, that's for non-tagged questions, as opposed to mistagged... but it seems close enough). In this case, I don't think it's a very large risk...